# XSS attack still works despite htmlspecialchars() doing its work

Tags: php, security, xss

hi i am trying to filter outputs of users who will put free text and wanna prevent XSS attacks so i tried this function i made to check

```
<?php
$patterns = [
    "<SCRIPT SRC=http://xss.rocks/xss.js></SCRIPT>",
    "javascript:/*--></title></style></textarea></script></xmp><svg/onload='+/\"/+/onmouseover=1/+/[*/[]/+alert(1)//'>",
    "javascript:alert('XSS');",
    "JaVaScRiPt:alert('XSS')",
    "javascript:alert(&quot;XSS&quot;)",
    "javascript:alert(\"RSnake says, 'XSS'\")",
    "\<a onmouseover=\"alert(document.cookie)\"\>xxs link\</a\>",
    "\<a onmouseover=alert(document.cookie)\>xxs link\</a\>",
    "<IMG \"\"\"><SCRIPT>alert(\"XSS\")</SCRIPT>\"\>",
    "javascript:alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))",
    "# onmouseover=\"alert('xxs')\"",
    " onmouseover=\"alert('xxs')\"",
    "x onerror=\"&#0000106&#0000097&#0000118&#0000097&#0000115&#0000099&#0000114&#0000105&#0000112&#0000116&#0000058&#0000097&#0000108&#0000101&#0000114&#0000116&#0000040&#0000039&#0000088&#0000083&#0000083&#0000039&#0000041\"",
    "&#106;&#97;&#118;&#97;&#115;&#99;&#114;&#105;&#112;&#116;&#58;&#97;&#108;&#101;&#114;&#116;&#40;&#39;&#88;&#83;&#83;&#39;&#41;",
    "&#0000106&#0000097&#0000118&#0000097&#0000115&#0000099&#0000114&#0000105&#0000112&#0000116&#0000058&#0000097&#0000108&#0000101&#0000114&#0000116&#0000040&#0000039&#0000088&#0000083&#0000083&#0000039&#0000041",
    "&#x6A&#x61&#x76&#x61&#x73&#x63&#x72&#x69&#x70&#x74&#x3A&#x61&#x6C&#x65&#x72&#x74&#x28&#x27&#x58&#x53&#x53&#x27&#x29",
    "jav    ascript:alert('XSS');",
    "jav&#x09;ascript:alert('XSS');",
    "jav&#x0A;ascript:alert('XSS');",
    "jav&#x0D;ascript:alert('XSS');",
    "<IMG SRC=java\0script:alert(\"XSS\")>",
    " &#14;  javascript:alert('XSS');",
    "<SCRIPT/XSS SRC=\"http://xss.rocks/xss.js\"></SCRIPT>",
    "<BODY onload!#$%&()*~+-_.,:;?@[/|\]^`=alert(\"XSS\")>",
    "<SCRIPT/SRC=\"http://xss.rocks/xss.js\"></SCRIPT>",
    "<<SCRIPT>alert(\"XSS\");//\<</SCRIPT>",
    "<SCRIPT SRC=http://xss.rocks/xss.js?< B >",
    "<SCRIPT SRC=//xss.rocks/.j>",
    "`<javascript:alert>`('XSS')",
    "http://xss.rocks/scriptlet.html <",
    'http://xss.rocks/xss.js',
    'http://xss.rocks/xss.js, http://xss.rocks/xss.js, http://xss.rocks/xss.js',
    "&lt;script&gt;alert('XSS')&lt;script/&gt;"
];
foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
$pattern = htmlspecialchars(htmlspecialchars($pattern));
?>
<iframe src="<?php echo $pattern; ?>"></iframe>
<iframe src="<?php echo $pattern; ?>" sandbox="allow-scripts"></iframe>
<img src="<?php echo $pattern; ?>">
<a href="<?php echo $pattern; ?>">Anchor</a>
<?php } ?>
```

i used `htmlspecialchars(htmlspecialchars($pattern))` to encode any `<` or `>` but it does not seem to prevent the attacks

and `iframe` without `allow-script` always runs the script as soon as it opens

i was wondering how to sanitize the input completely to prevent this attack completey

i only expect urls and when second link is clicked it runs a script too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't sanitize all type of XSS with `htmlspecialchars`.
`htmlspecialchars` may help you to protect against XSS inside HTML tags or some quoted HTML attributes.

You have to sanitize the different type of XSS with their own sanitization method.

---

1. User input placed inside HTML:

```
<p><?php echo $user_entered_variable; ?></p>
```

**Attack vector:**
`<script>alert(1)</script>`

This type of XSS can be sanitized using `htmlspecialchars` function because attacker need to use `<` and `>` to create new HTML tag.

**Solution:**

```
<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($user_entered_variable); ?></p>
```

---

2. User input placed inside single quoted attribute:

```
<img title='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($user_entered_variable);?>'/>
```

**Attack vector:**
`' onload='alert(1)' '`

`htmlspecialchars` will not encode single quote `'` by default. You must turn it on using `ENT_QUOTES` option.

**Solution:**

```
    <img title='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($user_entered_variable,ENT_QUOTES);?>'/>
```

---

3. User input placed inside URL attributes:
   `src`, `href`, `formaction`, `...`

```
    <iframe src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($user_entered_variable); ?>"></iframe>
    <img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($user_entered_variable); ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($user_entered_variable); ?>">Link</a>

    <script>function openLink(link){window.open(link);}</script>
    <button onclick="openLink('<?php echo htmlspecialchars($user_entered_variable); ?>')">JavaScript Window XSS</button>
```

**Attack vector:** `javascript:alert(1)`, `javscript://alert(1)`

[htmlspecialchars Document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

[image: PHP Document]

This function will not prevent those vectors because they haven't any HTML special character.
To prevent such attacks, you need to validate input as a URL.

**Solution:**

```
 <?php

 $user_entered_variable = htmlspecialchars($user_entered_variable);
 $isValidURL = filter_var($user_entered_variable, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== false;
 if(!$isValidURL)
    $user_entered_variable = 'invalid://invalid';
?>
    <iframe src="<?php echo $user_entered_variable; ?>"></iframe>
    <img src="<?php echo $user_entered_variable; ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $user_entered_variable; ?>">Link</a>

    <script>function openLink(link){window.open(link);}</script>
    <button onclick="openLink('<?php echo $user_entered_variable; ?>')">JavaScript Window XSS</button>
```

---

4. User input placed inside JavaScript tag without any quote

```
<script>
  var inputNumber = <?php echo $user_entered_variable; ?>
</script>
```

**Attack vector:** `1;alert(1)`

in some cases, we can easily quote input and prevent attack by sanitizing it using `htmlspecialchars` but if we need input to be integer we can prevent XSS by using input validation.

**Solution:**

```
<script>
  var inputNumber = <?php echo intval($user_entered_variable); ?>
</script>
```

---

**Always quote variables when it placed inside a HTML attribute and do a proper sanitization.**